# No rule to make target - Working with Resources in qt Creator

Tags: qt, makefile, resources, qt-creator, qmake

I started working with the qt Creator and I use the resource system with `qrc`-files. I am working on Windows 10 and I am using qt creator 3.6.1

Trying to run my project causes this Error: mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../Game/res/', needed by 'debug/qrc_res.cpp'.  Stop.

Clean Project, run qmake, Rebuild All did not help.

Game.pro looks fine. The specified pictures are in their places. I dont know how to resolve this problem. Can someone please help me? The only way I can resolve this problem so far, was to remove all qrc file from the project folder and project and add them again (by hand)...

my resourcefile `res.qrc`

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>res/1.png</file>
        <file>res/a.png</file>
        <file>res/#.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

A snippet of my `Game.pro`:

...

```
RESOURCES += \
    res.qrc \
    maps.qrc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the name of the `#.png` caused the error. The # probably is recognised as an escape character! I renamed it to `2.png`